# How do you investigate python's implementation of built-in methods?

Tags: python

I'm currently going through a basic compsci course. We use Python's `in` a lot. I'm curious how it's implemented, what the code that powers `in` looks like.

I can think of how *my* implementation of such a thing would work, but something I've learned after turning in a couple homework assignments is that my ways of doing things are usually pretty terrible and inefficient.. So I want to start investigating 'good' code.

Comment: `in` is an unfortunate example - it's not a single function (unless you count the underlying bytecode interpreter, but things are messy down there and does little but low-level bookkeeping itself), it's a method of the right operand. To make things worse, there is a special case that *does* have a default implementation, buried somewhere in the depths of the bytecode interpreter.

Comment: @delnan actually it isn't so bad, I went searching for it when I was extending my answer, and it just defers to a function in abstract.c, so you don't actually have to look at the bytecode interpreter to see the implementation of in.

Comment: @DevinJeanpierre Thanks, I'm not terribly familiar with such internals - I just knew `in` has its own bytecode instruction, should have guessed they re-use the code for the C-API implementation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The thing about builtin functions and types and operators and so on is that they are *not* implemented in Python. Rather, they're implemented in C, which is a much more painful and verbose programming language that won't always translate well to Python (usually because things are easier some other way in Python.)

With that said, you can investigate all of Python's implementation online, via their [public source repository](http://hg.python.org/cpython/).

The implementation for `in` is scattered -- there's one implementation per type, plus a more general implementation that calls the type-specific implementation (more on that later). For example, for lists, we'd look for the implementation of lists. In the Python source tree, the source for all builtin objects is in the Objects directory. In that directory you'll find listobject.c , which contains the implementation for the list object and all its methods.

On the repository at the time of answering, if you look at [line 393](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c310233b1d64/Objects/listobject.c#l393) you'll find the implementation of the in operator (also known as the `__contains__` method, which explains the name of the function). It's fairly straightforward, just loops through all the elements of the list until either the element is found, or there's no more elements, and returns the result of the search. :)

If it helps, in Python the idiomatic way to write this would be:

```
def __contains__(self, obj):
    for item in self:
        if item == obj:
            return True

    return False
```

---

I said earlier that there was a more general implementation. That can be seen in the implementation of [`PySequence_Contains`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c310233b1d64/Objects/abstract.c#l1943) in `abstract.c`. It tries to call the type-specific version, and if that fails, resorts to regular iteration. That loop there is what a regular Python for loop looks like when you write it in C (using the Python C-API).

Comment: C is painful? Only if you don't know it.

Comment: @Bryan , C is notoriously painful to debug. If you don't agree with the notoriety, fine. I didn't mean to start an argument. (To be fair, C is much easier to debug once you learn about Valgrind :)

Comment: I know C, and I know Python, and C is more painful. There is no Obfuscated Python Contest, although it has been suggested.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Data Model](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) section of the Python Language Reference:

> The membership test operators (`in` and `not in`) are normally implemented
>   as an iteration through a sequence. However, container objects can
>   supply the following special method with a more efficient
>   implementation, which also does not require the object be a sequence.
>
> `object.__contains__(self, item)`
>
> Called to implement membership test operators. Should return true if item is in self,
>   false otherwise. For mapping objects, this should
>   consider the keys of the mapping rather than the values or the
>   key-item pairs.
>
> For objects that don’t define `__contains__()`, the membership test first tries
>   iteration via `__iter__()`, then the old sequence iteration
>   protocol via `__getitem__()`, see this section in the language
>   reference.

So, by default Python iterates over a sequence to implement the `in` operator.  If an object defines the `__contains__` method, Python uses it instead of iterating.  So what happens in the `__contains__` method?  To know exactly, you would have to browse [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/).  But I can tell you that Python's lists implement `__contains__` using iteration.  Python dictionaries and sets are implemented as [hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), and therefore support faster membership testing.

Answer (score 2):

Python's built-in methods are written in the C language - you can see their code by checking out Python's source code yourself.

However, if you want to take a look of an equivalent implementation of all the methods in Python itself, you can check [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) - which features a Python implementation 100% written in Python and a subset of it (rpython).

The `in` operator calls the `__contains__` method in a string object - so you can check for the implementation of the string in both projects - but the actual searching code will be buried deeper.

Here is some of the code in CPython for it, for example:

http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c310233b1d64/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h

Comment: The "PyPy is in Python" argument is only half of the story. Truth is: RPython in practice is quite different from Python, and PyPy's Python interpreter is a highly flexible implementation of a quite complicated language. It's split across hundreds of files, uses lots of indirection, has all the complicated logic for all the special cases, has lots of code just for optimization, and frequently reaches back into *very* low-level code, including plain old C. It's as simple as it can be, but I wouldn't expect most undergrads to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

You can browse the Python-Source online: http://hg.python.org/

A good start is to clone the repository you need and then use `grep` to find the things you need.